# Case query in a where clause failed

Tags: sql-server

Please can someone help, I am trying to do a case statement in a where clause like this--- please see the query below

```
    SELECT  pisca ,
            dropbox
    FROM    Images
    WHERE   pisca = 'A'
            AND dropbox = CASE WHEN dropbox = 1 THEN 'Small'
                               WHEN dropbox = 2 THEN 'Medium'
                               WHEN dropbox = 3
                                    OR dropbox = 4 THEN 'Large'
                          END
```

But I am getting the following error messages

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'North' to data type int.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: I can't help you directly but I find it strange that you first compare `dropbox` to `int` (inside the CASE), then map it to `varchar` only to compare those `varchars` yet again to `dropbox`.

Comment: from the error it seems like the Column DropBox is defined as string and not integer. make sure the data type and the value your are using to compare against in CASE statement. also the CASE stmt is not build correctly.

Comment: This where clause doesn't make sense. You're saying "if dropbox equals one, see if it equals "Small".

Comment: Maybe you're passing in a parameter called @dropbox that could be 1,2,3,4 and that corresponds to the column in the table having "Small", "Medium", or "Large"? if so, change the `when dropbox = 1`'s to `when @dropbox = 1`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want this:

```
SELECT 
pisca ,
CASE dropbox 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Small'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Medium'
    WHEN 3 OR 4 THEN 'Large'
END dropbox
FROM  Images
WHERE pisca = 'A'
```

Comment: I'm guessing you're right that this is what they're looking for, unless it's what I said in the comment hat they're passing in an `int` @dropbox and comparing it to strings in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you whant to filter dropbox by name, like 'Small' try something like this:

```
SELECT
    I.pisca
,   D.DROPBOX
FROM Images I
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Small' AS DROPBOX
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Medium' AS DROPBOX
    UNION
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Large' AS DROPBOX
    UNION
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Large' AS DROPBOX
) D
    ON I.dropbox = D.ID
WHERE 
    I.pisca = 'A'
    AND D.DROPBOX = 'Small'
```

Answer (score -1):

as i mentioned check the data type if Dropbox is string or int and based on that use the one of this.

IF it is type INT

```
    SELECT  pisca ,
            dropbox
    FROM    Images
    WHERE   pisca = 'A'
            AND dropbox = CASE dropbox
                                WHEN 1 
                                    THEN 'Small'
                                WHEN 2 
                                    THEN 'Medium'
                                WHEN 3 
                                    THEN 'Large'
                                WHEN 4 
                                    THEN 'Large'
                          END
```

IF it is type String

```
    SELECT  pisca ,
            dropbox
    FROM    Images
    WHERE   pisca = 'A'
            AND dropbox = CASE dropbox
                                WHEN '1' 
                                    THEN 'Small'
                                WHEN '2' 
                                    THEN 'Medium'
                                WHEN '3' 
                                    THEN 'Large'
                                WHEN '4' 
                                    THEN 'Large'
                          END
```

Comment: This still doesn't make any sense. let's say that dropbox is '1'. Then youre going to be saying `where dropbox = 'Small'` even though you just confirmed it was '1'. This can never match any rows since one column can't be both '1' and 'small'.

Comment: yes I didn't focus on logically what OP is trying to achive, I have just corrected the CASE stmt he has written. either OP is looking for the query as Siddique has answered or the CASE condition is not based on dropbox but on some other column and OP is missing that. other wise why would I have where condition on dropBox and Case stmt is also on same column.